# Une femme tombe enceinte du pere ou de l'enfant?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot

Imaginons nous avons Marie et son époux Jean, ils ont leur fille Juliette.

Pour conter leur histoire, dira-t-on:

- **Marie tomba enceinte de Jean**

ou

- **Marie tomba enceinte de Juliette**
  ?

Merci d'avance!

Comment: Aussi *être enceinte de six mois*

Comment: [PONS](https://fr.pons.com/traduction/fran%C3%A7ais-anglais/enceinte) suggère que, dans le cas de *être enceinte* 'on utilise la même preposition pour toutes les trois situations (le père, l'enfant et la durée de grossesse.)

Answer (score 8):

Les deux sont possibles. Il s'agit en général du père mais on peut aussi tout a fait tomber enceinte de son premier enfant.

> Camille Lellouche enceinte de son premier enfant, elle dévoile son ventre bien rond.
>
> [Paris Match](https://www.parismatch.com/People/Camille-Lellouche-enceinte-de-son-premier-enfant-1806045), mai 2022

D'autre part, je conseillerais d'éviter *tomber* qui évoque une maladie, ce que la grossesse n'est pas, et d'utiliser *être*, *devenir*, *se retrouver* etc.

Comment: Si les deux sont possibles, alors la confusion se réinstalle.

Comment: @Seutchou En effet il peut y avoir confusion, mais à mon avis la plupart du temps elle est évitée par le fait qu'on sait de qui ont parle. Une mère ne dira probablement pas "j'étais enceinte de Jean" à quelqu'un qui ne connaît le nom ni de son fils, ni de son compagnon de l'époque. Et dans ce cas c'est tout à faire acceptable de demander qui est Jean. (Et bien sûr par le genre, sauf cas exceptionnel si Marie est enceinte de Juliette il est évident que c'est l'enfant)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Marie peut aussi être simultanément enceinte *du Père, du Fils et du Saint Esprit* :-)

Comment: *Marie est enceinte de trois mois du Fils du Père* - y-a-t-il un ordre de complement specifique? :-)

Comment: @RogerVadim Certainement, l'ordre de ta proposition est le seul qui tienne (un peu) la route.

Answer (score 2):

Comme on le note en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51361/une-femme-tombe-enceinte-du-pere-ou-de-lenfant#comment106638_51361), on peut avoir la préposition *de* pour indiquer la durée, la portée ou le géniteur ([Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/enceinte_1)) ; dans [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E1299?history=2) on parle d'abord de l'*état de grossesse* et on donne l'exemple « *Elle était alors enceinte de son premier enfant* » puis on dit « *Enceinte des œuvres de* ou *enceinte de*, expression utilisée pour désigner le père de l’enfant à naître. ». D'autre part, le TLFi dit de « [tomber](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tomber) enceinte » qu'il est *populaire*, construit sur le sens de *se retrouver* dans un état, sens qui peut être utile si c'est ce qu'on veut comme connotation et autrement on a identifié d'autres tournures dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51363). J'accepte toutes les formulations autant pour le géniteur que l'enfant.

La question présente deux phrases avec un seul complément mais en fin de compte c'est le contexte (et plus généralement l'ensemble du texte) et des précisions (*...de son premier enfant*, voire *...de sa première fille : Juliette.*) qui se doivent de faire la différence si on veut éviter l’ambiguïté (si Juliette eut plutôt été Jacques, par exemple).

Answer (score 1):

[Le Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/enceinte/29121) indique que ça désigne le père :

> **Être enceinte de quelqu'un,** attendre un enfant de lui.

Cependant, je n'ai pas réussi à trouver de sources pour l'autre sens mais il me semble que les deux sont possibles.